# Angular 6.x not working in IE 11 - Error: Invalid argument

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, angular6, internet-explorer-11, polyfills

I have an Angular 6.x app running perfectly in Chrome. The problem is when trying to run it in IE 11, I'm getting the error:

> Error: Invalid argument. at DefaultDomRenderer2.prototype.setProperty...

[image]

Already tried all answers in StackOverflow that I could find with no help. I'm listing theme here so you guys won't try them as answers:

- Added all polyfills needed for IE but still having the same problem.
- Added in head tag:

  ```
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">
  ```

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Don't support IE11 is my advice. Seriously.

If you really have to - I'd recommend updating your project to the latest version of Angular using `ng update`. I seem to recall they fixed an issue with some polyfills recently.

Comment: Can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I have created a new angular6 sample and add the header tag, it seems that everything works well on my side.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT I'll try to do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the problem and fixed it. I'm writing this answer to save time for others facing this problem.

**The problem** is binding an *incorrect* valued variable to an [HTML attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_attributes.asp) (any HTML attribute).

e.g.

Assigning a variable to a [*dir*](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_dir.asp) attribute in a *p* tag, **must** be defined with one of the possible values for *dir* attribute, which are: `ltr | rtl | auto`

Having this line in html: `<p [dir]="myDir">Test</p>`

When `myDir = undefined` or `myDir = 'bla bla bla'` or any other incorrect value - **we'll get an error**.

When `myDir = 'rtl'` or any other correct value - we **won't** get an error.

Added a [DEMO](https://ie-chrome-test.stackblitz.io/) to run in IE for seeing this error reproduced.

**For conclusion** I think we can say that when binding to an HTML attribute we'll have to be very careful to have a valid attribute's value, this way we won't face this problem.

Comment: Got the exact same message using `<input [type]="text">` instead of `<input type="text">` (in case someone else than me comes here after googling for this exact error message). No error messages with other browsers.

Comment: Same, but with `<textarea [rows]="rows">`  My component had an invalid value (rows was "-1") but in Chrome the DOM ended up with `rows="2"`, while in IE it was  still trying to set it to "-1".  Since changing it to a fn returning null for the -1 case to suppress the attribute entirely also didn't work, I ended up changing the binding to use `[attr.rows]`, which will successfully accept `null` and omit the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this error when using:

```
const input = {
   time: 'time',
   date: 'date'
}

<input [type]="input.date"/>
<input [type]="input.time"/>
```

IE 11 inputs don't support types of date and time. So any element that IE doesn't support will likely throw the same error.