# Debugging Angular 8 "Invalid argument" in IE11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, ie11-developer-tools

I've recently upgrade a large Angular application from 7.2 to 8. In IE11 I'm getting an error message `ERROR Error: Invalid argument`. I've read a couple of post that explain what the cause might be but I have no idea how to find the source of the problem. There is no stack trace or line number. I'm guessing the error is thrown from an Angular error handler which in IE11 gives very little detail?

Does anyone have any suggestions for debugging Angular 8 in IE11?

[image]

Related posts:

- [Angular 6.x not working in IE 11 - Error: Invalid argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53613452/angular-6-x-not-working-in-ie-11-error-invalid-argument)
- ["Error: Invalid argument." on IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37946579/error-invalid-argument-on-ie11)

Thanks

Comment: As we don't know anything about your project and there is no any sample for producing the issue. So it can be hard for providing any solid suggestion. Providing some random suggestions will make you more confused. For testing purpose, Try to upgrade an empty Angular 7.2 app to Angular 8 and confirm that it is working fine. You need to check your app by dividing it in to segments can make this process simple.

Comment: I'm confident that an empty Angular project will work correctly. Judging by other reports it is an issue with an element argument being set incorrectly. I presume that it a attribute value that is initially undefined. However, it is a large project and I don't know how to track it down without more information. I have started the process of disabling sections of the application. But this is hindered by another bug when using `serve` https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14777 meaning I have to publish each time I disable a section (about a seven min build!). I really need a stack trace

Comment: You have to go through your whole code to check which attribute value is undefined. there is no any other way to get the information about the cause for this error.